# Clicking a button to update text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<button id="addText" onclick="addText()">Add Text</button><br>
```

I'm trying to have this button call this function to update a text field. I don't want it to go to an action page or anything. The display aspect isn't even important. I'm just trying to find out how to update a variable in the background with a button click.

```
function addText(){
    // create a new div element 
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    // and give it some content 
    var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 
    // add the text node to the newly created div
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  
    // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: *update a variable in the background*... which variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function addText(){
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "your change text";
}
```